# Handling response to AJAX from servlet

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets, ajaxform

This is my servlet class code where I am setting response.

```
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        if(status.equals("Fail")) {
            out.println(status);  
        }else {
            out.println(status);  
        }

        out.flush();
```

This is my AJAX where I need to show a message depending upon SUCCESS/FAIL response from Servlet.

```
           $.ajax({
                    url: "ImportFile",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: new FormData(document.getElementById("fileForm")),
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success :function(data) {
                           console.log('RESPONSE: ',data);
                           if(data == "Success"){
                               $(".impostSuccess").modal('show');
                           }else{
                               $(".impostFail").modal('show');
                           }
                           file.val('');
                       },
                       error :function(err){
                           file.val('');
                           console.log('RESPONSE: ',data);
                       }   
            });
```

Wherever my response is "Success", Else part is executing and that modal is shown.

How should I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

you can show message like this

```
       $.ajax({
                url: "ImportFile",
                type: "POST",
                data: new FormData(document.getElementById("fileForm")),
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success :function(res) {
                       console.log('RESPONSE: ',res);
                       $(".impostSuccess").modal('show');
                       file.val('');
                   },
                   error :function(err){
                       file.val('');
                       console.log('RESPONSE: ',err);
                       $(".impostFail").modal('show');

                   }   
        });
```

Comment: Thanks.. But here my code AJAX is executing success:function() ... all the time unless.. there are errors in sending or receiving request/response
Hence... I want to handle fail/Success message in "success :function(res)"